# Фильтрация столбцов в таблице Excel или PowerBI

Tags: sql, excel, powerbi

Могу ли я как-то в Excel или, лучше, в PowerBi сделать выборку срезом столбцов, которые мне нужно визуализировать?

В sql я могу написать запрос, select col1, col2 from table - могу ли я точно так же делать выборку только тех столбцов, которые мне нужны в Экселе или PowerBI?

Допустим, из отчета мне нужна информация только по нескольким городам

Comment: Можно в VBA. Данные в массив, из массива нужные данные пишутся в другой массив.  Проще (тоже макросом): копировать лист, в копии удалить столбцы, если нужно, заорузить почищенные данные в массив, временный лист удалить.

Comment: Спасибо!) Так и в Power BI можно? и через кнопочки среза будет работать такая фильтрация?

Comment: Увы, не знаю. В VBA можно.

Comment: Разбейте таблицу на несколько разных таблиц в редакторе запросов. Обязательно проставьте связи в PBI. Если нужно подробное решение, вышлите файл пример.